# feedback controller for percentual variables

Tags: math, integer, double, pid, feedback

I am working on a control system which controls a system based on percentual parameters.

Both the setpoint and output data are in percentages, as well as the integer value which is being controlled.

I am having trouble figuring out how to use a proper feedback controller for this kind of situation, especially since many seem to rely on non-integer values.

For example, if we look at a proportional controller I am left with a few values I cannot use.

if setpoint is 60, and output is 80; we take a gain of 0.5
Use the error which is 20*0.5 = 10. The controller logic will then add 10 to the integer value, there is nothing wrong with this approach.

but what is the setpoint is 61, and output is 86; with the same gain of 0.5.
Using the error, which is now 25*0.5 = 12,5. We now have a value which I cannot add to my integer value, since integers don't support doubles. Rewriting the software whereas doubles are used, is not possible.

I am very new to these types on controllers, and I would like some advice on this problem or some sources which can help me understand how to tackle this properly if possible.

Comment: I don't understand, why would you need integers? There's nothing special about percentages, you can have 81.83276497128641984% of something just fine? You just round to however many digits you need for the human-readable part of your application, but internally, use as many digits as your signal maths requires? Do you mean you're using an int datatype for percentages? (in which case as a fellow programmer I'd explicitly point that out as almost certainly a bug, only the derivative presentation form should be a whole number, although even that's not true depending on the application of course)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I completely agree with your datatype assessment, using integers to display percentages is somewhat of a comical choice considering what percentages are. However, yes this is implemented this way; not by me however. This means that I can calculate to as many digits as I want just fine, I just cannot input them as such. Which leaves rounding as an option, though doesn't that defeat the whole point of an accurate feedback controller?

Comment: Then you'll have to come up with a rounding policy for the controller's output before you apply it, and whoever's code this is: they will have to live with the fact that there will be oscillation. And hopefully someone can file an issue along the lines of "switch percentage data type from int to float" because you don't solve a problem by hoping this is the only time it'll come up =D